# index.php require results in 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, centos

I've been looking for a long time, but I can't find the problem at all and this is supposed to be simple...

I have no  problem running my index.php file (eg. echo "test";), but the moment I try to require another php file, I get a "500 internal server error" message.

```
require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/test.php');
```

These files are under /var/www/html 
I've got no clue what is the problem.

I'm on a VPS running CentOS 6.4.

Do you have some guidelines where I can locate the problem?
Perhaps some configuration issue?
I'm really out of options.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in the PHP or web server logs?

Comment: I checked the folder /var/log/httpd but I couldn't find anything unusual. Anything I should be looking for?

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file in that directory? What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: I don't have an htaccess file currently.

Comment: Run `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` on the terminal to monitor incoming error log messages. Load the site index.php in your browser. You should be able to know the reason for the 500 internal server error.

Comment: I did, but no extra error message appears at all. Also in the error log, I can't find any new error. I've been experimenting; it works to echo the path, but I just can't seem to require it. It's driving me crazy and I'm wasting so much time on this ridiculous problem.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that your file exitsts and is readable ?

verify that by `var_dump(is_readable(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/test.php'));`

Comment: probably file doesn't exist.

in that case you got fatal when you are trying to require that file, fix path to the file :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that open_basedir was set to the wrong path.
After adapting it to:

php_admin_value open_basedir

```
/var/www/html/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php54/lib/php/
```

Everything is fine! 
I think that I have made a wrong configuration here in the past when I was careless, while configuring other virtual hosts in the same file.

I'm not sure why I didn't immediately get feedback in the error logs, but the problem is solved anyway.